# how to check in given string any spanish character is available or not using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi can some give me the idea of how to check in given string suppose='name' name has any Spanish character using javascript? so pls help me with this thanks in advance.

Comment: `var hasCharacter = /[ñáéíóúü]/gi.test(input);` with input being the value you want to check

Comment: In order to complete the [regex character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html) have a look at [ALT Codes for Spanish Letters with Accents or Diacritics](https://altcodeunicode.com/alt-codes-for-spanish-letters-with-accents-or-diacritics/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkSpanish(name) {
  return /[ñáéíóú]/gi.test(name)
}

console.log(checkSpanish('Stephan')); // false
console.log(checkSpanish('Stéphan')); // true
```

Comment: In order to complete the [regex character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html) have a look at [ALT Codes for Spanish Letters with Accents or Diacritics](https://altcodeunicode.com/alt-codes-for-spanish-letters-with-accents-or-diacritics/).